# How to determine what type of layers do I need for my Deep learning model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, tflearn

Suppose that I have want to make a model that does something. Now when I search about the topic in Google or YouTube, I find many related tutorials and it seems like some clever programmer had already implemented that model with Deep learning.

But how do they know that what type of layers, what type of activation functions, loss functions, optimizer, number of units etc. they need to solve that certain problem using deep learning.

Are there any techniques for knowing this, or its just a matter of understanding and experience? Also it would be very helpful if somebody could point me to some videos or articles answering my question.

Comment: The question does not belong on SO. It has nothing to do with programming itself. You could ask this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead, but not here

Comment: This is an area of active research. Google has some efforts to make the architecture something learnable. In general I suggest starting out with a known good configuration such as VGG net, for example, until you understand each of the components and how they are applied. You'll understand more about the architectural choices by reading the Deep Learning Book (online and in print). There's no silver bullet answer to this question. At least not in the year 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a matter of understanding and experience. When building a model from scratch, you must understand which optimizer, loss, etc. makes sense for your particular problem. In order to choose these appropriately, you must understand the differences between the available optimizers, loss functions, etc.

In regards to choosing how many layers and nodes, what batch size, what learning rate, etc.-- these are all *hyperparameters* that you will need to test and tune as you experiment with your model.

I have a [Deep Learning Fundamentals YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xq7LwI2y8_QtvuXZedL6tQU) that you may find helpful. It covers the fundamental basics of each of these topics in short videos. Additionally, this [Deep Learning with Keras playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL) may also be beneficial if you're wanting to focus more on coding after getting the basic concepts down.

Comment: Your playlists are really very helpful. Keep working like this. God bless you.

Comment: Thanks, Snehanshu! FYI, I've just updated the links to the playlist. My content moved to a new channel.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question.

1. The **CS231n Stanford lectures on CNN** is the best for beginners refer to the video lectures [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC1qU-LWwrF64f4QKQT-Vg5Wr4qEE1Zxk) and class notes are available [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)
2. After watching the lectures and completing the assignments, you will get a basic idea of what Deep Learning is and all the algorithms available etc.
3. But when it comes to solving real-world problems this won't be sufficient So take [this course](http://www.fast.ai/) by Jeremy Howard where he teaches more on how to approach a problem using Kaggle platform.
4. Keep on solving more problems experimenting new models and algorithms using several platforms like hackerearth, Kaggle, topcoder etc.